# How to generate .keystore file using Google App Signing certificate?

Tags: android, google-play, android-app-signing

What I have done

1. I've created app, signed it as described [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html)
2. I've uploaded the generated bundle to Google Play and got access to the page with App signing certificate and Upload certificate

Now what? How do i create new .keystore file using App signing certificate or Upload certificate? Also, which one should i use?

I'm on OS X, if this is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keystore you used to sign the App Bundle or your APK is the one you need to use to sign all future versions of your app. It contains your upload key and certificate. 
The release key has been automatically generated by Play and will be used to to sign the APKs served to the users of you app. Play shows you the certificate associated with that key just for information purposes.

You don't need to do anything else, in particular no need to create a new keystore. Use the same keystore you created initially to sign all your future APKs or App Bundles, and you're good to go.

Comment: this is wrong. The whole point of this process is to not to use original cert

Comment: You are confusing the process for new apps and for existing apps: for existing apps, indeed, the private key is transferred to Play and a new key must be created that becomes your upload key. However, for new apps, if you enrolled in App Signing by Play when uploading your first artifact, then Play creates the release key for you and the key you used to sign your artifact is interpreted by Play as being the upload key, so no need to create a new key. I should know, I implemented it ;)

Comment: If you're still not convinced, I invite you to take a look at the [official documentation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423). See the section for "New apps".

Comment: yep, you are right. Then question is how to generate additional upload key. Looks like the only way is to contact support?

Comment: I don't understand why you want to generate an *additional* upload key.
The key you signed your APK with is already different from the key used to sign the APK that is served to your users, which is the whole concept of Play Signing.

You can if you want *reset* your upload key by contacting support, but that's only useful if your key was either compromised, or if you lost it.

Comment: @pierre I am uploading a new app, but each time i try to load my first apk it show me this error: You have uploaded an APK or an Android App Bundle signed with a key also used to sign APKs provided to users. Participate in the Google Play app signing program, so you should sign the APK or the Android App Bundle with a new key before uploading it.

Why?

Comment: This is unrelated to this issue. Open a new thread and add the "android-app-signing" tag, I'll answer there to avoid polluting this thread.